# not able to load properties file with runnable jar

Tags: java, maven, properties, classloader, quartz-scheduler

I have maven project in Java in which I have a property file (quartz.properties) under this directory:

```
/src/main/resources
```

Now I can use this property file in two ways from this class as shown below:

```
/**
 * Create a StdSchedulerFactory that has been initialized via
 * <code>{@link #initialize(Properties)}</code>.
 *
 * @see #initialize(Properties)
 */
public StdSchedulerFactory(Properties props) throws SchedulerException {
    initialize(props);
}

/**
 * Create a StdSchedulerFactory that has been initialized via
 * <code>{@link #initialize(String)}</code>.
 *
 * @see #initialize(String)
 */
public StdSchedulerFactory(String fileName) throws SchedulerException {
    initialize(fileName);
}
```

So I started using like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    StdSchedulerFactory factory = new StdSchedulerFactory();
    try {
        factory.initialize(TestClassName.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("quartz.properties"));
        Scheduler scheduler = factory.getScheduler();
        scheduler.start();
    } catch (SchedulerException ex) {
        System.out.println("error= " + ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(ex));
    }
}
```

This works fine without any issues in my windows laptop but when I make a runnable jar (export --> runnable jar --> Package required libraries into generated JAR) and then if I run like this on my other ubuntu machine:

```
java -jar abc.jar
```

I am getting this exception:

```
error= org.quartz.SchedulerException: Error loading property data from InputStream - InputStream is null.
        at org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory.initialize(StdSchedulerFactory.java:576)
        at com.example.quartz.TestClassName.main(TestClassName.java:17)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:58)
```

What is wrong I am doing?

**Update:-** Output from `jar tvf abc.jar` . I am just showing relevant things not all.

```
    13 Thu Sep 10 18:16:30 GMT-07:00 2015 resources/build.properties
   594 Thu Sep 10 18:16:30 GMT-07:00 2015 resources/quartz.properties
  1254 Thu Sep 10 18:16:30 GMT-07:00 2015 resources/quartz_config.xml
```

Comment: Are you sure it's `quartz.properties` rather than `Quartz.properties`? Can you run `jar tvf abc.jar` and show the output?

Comment: Why do you create your jar file using your IDE, instead of doing it with Maven?

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes it is `quartz.properties`. I can see it clearly in my laptop and it does work fine locally. Updating the question as well.

Comment: @JBNizet I have been using this from a long time so thought to use it like this. If I need to use it through maven, then just run mvn clean install and use the jar from `maven.repo`?

Comment: Now you've posted that, it's simple...

Comment: It completely defeats the purpose of using a build tool like Maven if you build your jar without it, by having to start an IDE and click on buttons, and resulting in a jar file that doesn't have the expected layout it would have if you used Maven.

Comment: I tried doing your way but I got this error - `no main manifest attribute, in abc-1.0.0.jar`

Comment: Yes, you need to read the Maven documentation and add the needed configuration in the pom.xml file to make it generate a runnable jar file. It won't happen magically. Maven can't guess what your main class is. Why do you use Maven if you don't plan to actually use it to build your artefacts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your file is in the jar file as `resources/quartz.properties`, not just `quartz.properties` - so that's how you need to load it:

```
factory.initialize(
  TestClassName.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("resources/quartz.properties"));
```

Alternatively, create the jar file differently so that `quartz.properties` is in the "root" directory of the jar file. (That's where I'd expected it to be, given the file system structure you've described.)

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. How can I make this generic - meaning whenever I run it locally it should work automatically and whenever I run it as a runnable jar as `java -jar abc.jar` in my ubuntu machine, then it should work as well. Is there any better way through maven that can do for me whenever I can make a jar file?

Comment: @user1950349: As I said in the answer, you could change where the file ends up in the resource file - when you add the resources to the jar file, add the contents of the `resources` directory as root elements, rather than adding the `resources` directory itself.

Comment: Ok understood that but how can I do that? I have never done that before. Is it through eclipse (as that's what I am using here) or something else?

Comment: @user1950349: You'd probably want to either move the `resources` directory (e.g. as a top-level directory) or add it as a resource root in Eclipse, or change how you package the jar file. Read the documentation on what "Package required libraries into generated JAR" does for details.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access `resources/build.properties` from your class you need to use the absolute path as in:

```
TestClassName.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/resources/quartz.properties")
```

Comment: Using slash before resources will change the class path and will not seach the properties in the project. It should be used as   'TestClassName.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("resources/quartz.properties")' as @Jon skeet mentioned.

Comment: Depending on the package of your `TestClassName`. The one I mentioned is the absolute path for the resource. If you remove slash it is relative path from the class package. If it is in default package both are same. But if your `TestClassName` is in package `foo` the resource path will become `/foo/...'.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you should ensure quartz.properties in jar file. If it does not exist , you need to check the build setting in pom.xml